# How to compare two ints in expect shell?

Tags: shell, expect

I want subtract a number in `expect shell` until it equals 0, then close this shell, such as :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set round [lindex $argv 0];
incr round -1
if round <= 0 close  // ??how to write this sentence?
```

Comment: Expect uses the [tag:tcl] language. the doc is at https://www.tcl.tk/doc/ . you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more familiar with shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line would be:

```
if {$round <= 0} exit
```

BUT I think you actually want to decrement the counter repeatedly, for which you would need a loop:

```
while {$round > 0} {
    incr round -1
}
```